# if condition comes from a string variable

Tags: php, if-statement

I am making a quiz online for my students and I have a variable

```
$no_of_questions = 7;
```

and based on that value I need to generate the condition of my IF statement

```
if ($row['q1'] === NULL OR $row['q2'] === NULL OR $row['q3'] === NULL OR ....)
```

That is php code so I can't echo and I can't put a string into IF and work as wanted. Any ideas on how to solve it?

Comment: i am not sure what you are asking, you can create a from, and can store their value in variable or array, and can achieve this??

Comment: It's unclear to me what the question is as well...

Comment: I retrieve some values from mysql and I want to check each value that it is not null and if only one is null do some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply achieve this with a for()-loop.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= $no_of_questions; $i++) {
    if($row['q'.$i] === NULL) {
        //do something if one question is NULL
    }
}
```

Comment: That will cause the code to be executed every time there is a NULL I just want it to be done once if any of them is null.

Comment: but this sounds promising, I might break after my first null.

Comment: @Abkarino you need a break inside the if.

Comment: @Abkarino Nope, I'll execute the code for every question from q1 up to qX (X equals no_of_questions) if it equals NULL. You can break the loop if you want to stop if it encounters the first question equaling NULL.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois you deserve the accept, I'll step out instead.

Comment: @Theraot And what I've seen from your code, you're overcompensating something. You don't need to define a variable true and then do something after the loop. You can do that in that loop. Just the break is important.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand from your question. This will work.

```
$i=1;

if( $a['q'.$i] === NULL)
```